# How to solve ConfigurationException: Missing required directive CommitLogSync while configuring a multi node Cassandra cluster on Centos7?

Tags: centos7, cassandra

**Aim:** to configure a multi node Cassandra cluster on Centos7

---

**Method**

[This documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/initialize/initializeSingleDS.html) is used to configure a multi node Cassandra cluster.

```
[user@cassandra01 ~]$ cat /etc/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml
cluster_name: 'MyCassandraCluster'
num_tokens: 256
seed_provider:
  - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
    parameters:
      - seeds: "<ipaddress_cassandra01>,<ipaddress_cassandra02>"
listen_address:
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
```

---

**Problem**

When the first Cassandra node has been started by issuing:

```
sudo systemctl start cassandra
```

the node does not seem to start and the `/var/log/cassandra/cassandra.log` indicates that:

```
 INFO 12:56:38,057 Loading settings from file:/etc/cassandra/default.conf/cassandra.yaml
 INFO 12:56:40,073 Data files directories: null
 INFO 12:56:40,089 Commit log directory: null
ERROR 12:56:40,097 Fatal configuration error
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Missing required directive CommitLogSync
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applyConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:148)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.<clinit>(DatabaseDescriptor.java:112)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:213)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:554)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:643)
Missing required directive CommitLogSync
Fatal configuration error; unable to start. See log for stacktrace.
```

---

**Attempt to solve the issue**

According the error message it looks like that there is a configuration issue or certain directories do not exist.

1) `Missing required directive CommitLogSync`:

According [this documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html) there is a default `commitlog_sync`, i.e.:

> commitlog_sync
>       (Default: periodic ) The method that Cassandra uses to acknowledge writes in milliseconds:
>
> ```
>     periodic : Used with commitlog_sync_period_in_ms (Default: 10000 - 10 seconds ) to control how often the commit log is
> ```
>
> synchronized to disk. Periodic syncs are acknowledged immediately.
>           batch : Used with commitlog_sync_batch_window_in_ms (Default: disabled **) to control how long Cassandra waits for other writes
>   before performing a sync. When using this method, writes are not
>   acknowledged until fsynced to disk.

2) `Data files directories: null`:

> data_file_directories
>       (Default: /var/lib/cassandra/data ) The directory location where table data (SSTables) is stored.

Issuing `ls /var/lib/cassandra/data` returns a `0` and indicates that the directory exists.

3) `Commit log directory: null`:

> commitlog_directory
>       (Default: /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog ) The directory where the commit log is stored. For optimal write performance, it is recommended
>   the commit log be on a separate disk partition (ideally, a separate
>   physical device) from the data file directories.

Confirmed that the `/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog` directory exists as well.

---

**Question**

What is causing this issue and how to solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the documentation indicates that there are default settings, the software itself requires that these are defined in the cassandra.yaml. Defining the following in `/etc/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml`:

```
data_file_directories:
  - /var/lib/cassandra/data
commitlog_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog
saved_caches_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches
```

and restarting cassandra solved the issue.

Comment: So this is a documentation bug then...